# Community Promotion Ads — 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2019 is here! And with the new year, as usual, comes a new iteration of **Community Promotion Ads**! Let’s refresh these for the coming year :)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting chemistry research sites
- useful resources for practitioner and student alike
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4364).

Answer (score 13):

[image: Visit our meta site!]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Astronomy Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Answer (score 10):

[image: The Periodic Table. Come chat with us!]

Answer (score 9):

[image: VESTA]

Answer (score 9):

[image: shapecatcher.com]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Quantum Computing Stack Exchange]

Comment: Designed by [DanielSank](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/31790/danielsank).

Answer (score 8):

[image: Avogadro - the open molecular editor]

Comment: Actually, I'll have an updated version of this, but thanks for re-posting. Good to know people still like it. :-)

Comment: @GeoffHutchison I have definitely found the program useful and figure the decent number of computationalists on the site would as well. Feel free to update this answer when you have a new version.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison The new Community Post for 2020 is online, so if you'd like to add the updated version there, I guess that would be appreciated by not only me.

Answer (score 8):

[image: NIST CompChem Comparison & Benchmark Database]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Zotero]

Answer (score 4):

[image: The LaTeX Project]

Answer (score 4):

[image: MarvinSketch]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Olex2]

Answer (score 0):

[image: DataWarrior]

Comment: It could perhaps do with some text saying what this is.

Comment: Datawarrior is a free software, as far as I know mainly used in drug design.
It features some interesting functions: it is capable of retrieving molecules from several databases. Plus, molecules can be filtered by substructure, name, molecular weight, and when available by biochemical or physical properties.

Comment: I guess @orthocresol meant that the illustration may benefit from adding the actual name of the program alongside with a short descriptive caption that reflects its functionality. I'm afraid for a person who has no idea what this software is capable of (e.g. the target audience of the ad) it's not clear what a screenshot is supposed to represent.

Comment: Sorry, I might be bad at googling, but I couldn't find the logo online, I only found this picture .-.

Comment: Assuming you are using the program you are recommending, why search online when you can extract all icons from the executable? On Windows it can be done with [IconsExtract](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html) (run on `C:\Program Files\DataWarrior\DataWarrior.exe`).

Comment: I found the main logo and what looks like six subroutine ICO files and converted these to PNG images: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G7pp.png); [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP1mr.png); [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nUln.png); [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IQxq.png); [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leGSw.png); [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dom1G.png); [7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnSAr.png). Feel free to grab any of these if you need. They may not look nice, but at least these icons are officially bundled with DataWarrior.

Answer (score -6):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting